# Why does my React Native snack generate a vector-icon error message?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the following Snack:

https://snack.expo.io/BJ4-sqpgN

I'm getting the error message:

> Device: (1002:881) Unable to resolve module
>   'module://@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome5.js'   Evaluating
>   module://@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome5.js   Evaluating
>   module://native-base.js   Evaluating module://App.js   Loading
>   module://App.js

I've tried adding `@expo/vector-icons` to package.json, but I get:

```
package.json: (5:5) The package "@expo/vector-icons" can be imported without adding to "dependencies"
```

How do I fix the original error?

Answer (score 1):

Because Expo dont have FontAwesome5 yet.Check this [issue](https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/58)